# Forge Viewer shows different data from Model Derivative data on IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

This is a process that I've always used. First I call the bulk data from model derivative for further structuring. But this time the derivative data is confusing. Because when I use `getProperties` from viewer it shows external id with expected format`(0/0/0/145/79)` but when the **same element** is called from derivative api, on the field of external id, `ifcGUID (11h5ts$FhghhDGbOs)` is written.

In short I can not get external id of element from derivative Api but it can be found from viewer.
What could cause to such confusion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have uploaded the model with `SVF` format instead of `SVF2` and it looks like everything is working fine and as expected. But I think this topic needs further investigation.

Comment: You need to make sure you tell the system which IDs you are using.
In the Viewer, are you loading model as SVF2? Or SVF? That will make a difference.
SVF:
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    api: 'derivativeV2' + (emea ? '_EU' : ''),
SVF2:
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: (emea ? 'streamingV2_EU' : 'streamingV2'),

Comment: Using the Derivative service, you also need to tell which one you are using x-ads-derivative-format
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/