# SVF2 format retrieves missing or incorrect data from Model Derivative on IFC and RVT

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

This question is connected another issue which I've posted before here: [Inconsistent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775683/forge-viewer-shows-different-data-from-model-derivative-data-on-ifc-file).

When models are uploaded with `SVF2` format, [Model Derivative](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) brings wrong data like `(IfcGUID on externalId field or names on externalId field instead of real external id)` or msising data like `(names without [Revit ID], missing properties)`. But from viewer with `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` right data and structure can be seen without any issue.

When the models are uploaded with older version `SVF` format there are no problems.

What could be the real issue here, should we not use `SVF2` yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think it's "wrong datas". With SVF2, the metadata endpoint will provide SVF2 data according to this [SVF2 Metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-2-metadata)

So I guess it's normal you have some differences between your SVF and SVF2 data.

For the viewer part, I know you can change some parameters to specify whether you're working with SVF or SVF2 : [Viewer initializer options](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/preperation/#displaying-svf-svf2-files-in-the-viewer)

Hope it will help